# c++20 Check a String at compile time for substrings

Tags: c++, fmt

I'm looking for a way to check a format string at compile time for invalid characters.
I'm using the fmt Lib to format my string.

Unfortunately fmt lib allows to use printf() formatters (like %s, %i) in strings. My Log function may be called from C or C++ context.
From C context we have to rely on printf() syntax, but from C++ context we can use python like formatters ({:d} etc.).

I'd like to print a compiler error if old printf() syntax is used from C++ context.

I did came up with this. However I'm getting some compiler errors. Could you help me out getting rid of them?.
Thx :)

https://godbolt.org/z/Ko5GhMMPn

Edit: As requested I pasted my code into this question as well

```
#include <source_location>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <iostream>


#pragma once

#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std::string_view_literals;

///some possible printf format args to look for
constexpr auto printfFormatArgs = std::array{ "%s"sv, "%i"sv, "%d"sv };

struct CompileTimeStringCheck
{
  std::string_view str;

  consteval CompileTimeStringCheck(std::string_view name)
    :str(name)
  {
    if (std::ranges::find(printfFormatArgs, name) != printfFormatArgs.end())
      throw;
  }
};

inline void checkCompileTimeString(CompileTimeStringCheck name)
{
}


#ifdef __cplusplus
#define LOG_MESSAGE(strLogMessage, ...) log(strLogMessage, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
//shown just for completeness => called from C Code
LOG_MESSAGE(strLogMessage, ...) logFromC(strLogMessage, __FILE__, _LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#endif //#ifdef __cplusplus

void _log(std::string_view formatedMsg,  const std::source_location loc = std::source_location::current())
{
    //do the actual logging....
    //just as dummy
    checkCompileTimeString(formatedMsg);
    std::cout << formatedMsg<< "loc"<< loc.file_name() <<loc.line() << std::endl;
}
template <typename... Args>
void log(
      fmt::format_string<Args...> fmt, 
      Args&&... args
    )
    {
        std::string strFormatedMessage = fmt::format(fmt, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        _log(std::move(strFormatedMessage));
    }



int main()
{
    std::string foo = "foo";
    LOG_MESSAGE("foo {}",foo);  //< Succeed
    LOG_MESSAGE("fail %s",foo); //< should show error
    LOG_MESSAGE("fail %s"); //< should also fail

}
```

Comment: Please add your code and the errors directly to the question. The link is great but it doesn't allow the code to be searched here and folks interested in answering your question may not be able to follow it to do so.

Comment: Your use of `std::ranges::find` isn't working because the default predicate is equality comparison.  According to your question, you're looking for a substring match aka "contains" test.

Comment: You're also mistakenly testing the result of formatting, instead of the format template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are quite a few things wrong with your code, I adopted a different tack.  I elected to write a simple `consteval` function to check that the format string doesn't contain any `%` characters (unless immediately followed by another one).  I then call this from the `LOG_MESSAGE` macro, and then, all being well, call `log`.

Here's the code.  Note that the format string must be a literal (I think that would be true however you do it):

```
#include <source_location>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

consteval bool check_format (const char *fmt)
{
    while (*fmt)
    {
        if (*fmt == '%')
        {
            if (fmt [1] != '%')
                 return false;
            ++fmt;
            if (*fmt == 0)
                break;
        }
        ++fmt;
    }    
    return true;
}

#define LOG_MESSAGE(fmt, ...) \
    static_assert (check_format (fmt)); \
    log (std::source_location::current (), fmt, __VA_ARGS__);

template <class... Args>
void log (const std::source_location loc, std::format_string <Args...> fmt, Args&&... args)
{
    std::string strFormatedMessage = format (fmt, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    std::cout << strFormatedMessage << " File " << loc.file_name() << ", line " << loc.line() << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::string foo = "foo";
    LOG_MESSAGE("{}", foo);     // works
//  LOG_MESSAGE("fail %s",foo); // generates compiler error
//  LOG_MESSAGE("fail %s");     // ditto, although a different one
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hjVdNVsM8BUTpHSv)

Comment: Hey Paul, thx for your answer :) this works. However in my dummy mock i forget that log() actually returns a boolean. When returning a boolean this will fail. Is there a way to add the static check to the log function directly? https://godbolt.org/z/nnnno4d8Y  Thx for your help so far :)

Comment: @JHeni See [modified demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/G9t4xACSKWe6wfw7).  But why is `log` returning anything?  What are you going to do if it fails?

Comment: Thx for your fast replay :) In my case log actually places the data into a queue, and a low prio thread is writing it to the hardware. However if the queue is full or if writing to the hardware failed I'd like to know that. In cases where critical errors are logged I need a retry ;)